# How to make and call a function in VCL form application

Tags: c++, function, undefined

I am using C++ Builder, and am after some help to make a function for some form actions. I have tried the code below, with no luck.

Here is my code:

```
int calculateAndDisplayImportantAppointments()
{
    int integerNumberOfImportantAppointments = calCalendar.getNumberOfImportantAppointments();
    if (integerNumberOfImportantAppointments > 0)
    {
        // itoa is not standard (like any of this is)
        WCHAR strN[32];
        swprintf(strN, L"%d", integerNumberOfImportantAppointments);

        // not familiar with ShowMessage(), but I *think* this will work.
        ShowMessage("You have " + UnicodeString(strN) + " important appointments. Do you wish to view them?");
    }

    return integerNumberOfImportantAppointments;
}
```

I am getting the following error: Call to undefined function `calculateAndDisplayImportantAppointments` when trying to call this function.

Can I please have some help in fixing this problem?

Comment: First of all, please edit your question to include _how_ you call this function. Secondly, do you have your project is multiple source files? And if so, are you properly building the project with all source files?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, very simple solution.

The function needs to be written above the section of code that declares it.